# Establish Linux to Windows connection

Tags: windows, linux, connection, remote

We can establish connection between Unix based machines using these commands -

```
ssh
telnet
```

but how to establish a connection between a Linux and Windows? `Putty, WinSCP` etc are used in Windows to connect to Linux. But how do I connect **to** windows **from** Linux?(or is it even possible?)

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to a windows host in the same way you would connect to a linux host. You just have to set up an ssh or telnet server on the windows machine.

Comment: See e.g. this for a walkthrough: http://pigtail.net/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html (used it and works flawlessly)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the "rdesktop" command to connect to a windows machine...

Comment: What kinda connection does it establish? Telnet?ssh?

Comment: by default it connects to tcp port 3389 in the windows machine, so its not ssh nor telnet

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do.

NT Server edition comes with a telnet daemon - but telnet is far from secure. You can run an ssh server on MSWindows - but you still only get access to the NT command prompt - which is very limited.

If you want to access a MSWindows machine from Linux, then you probably want to use a remote frame buffer solution like [vnc](http://www.realvnc.com/), [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/), [Citrix](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/home.asp) or just use the built-in remote desktop server in MSWindows with [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/)